# Setting wifi network priorities to avoid xfinity wifi

Tags: wireless

xfinity wifi hijacks my system, so that even when I'm at home, I connect to xfinity rather than my much stronger home networks.    I'd like to set a priority system so that good networks that I know (like my home networks) trump xfinity.    It was hopeful that [wifi-radar](http://wifi-radar.tuxfamily.org/) would accomplish this, but read on this site that it was no longer ubuntu friendly (and I can't get it to set a configuration file).     Is there any way to accomplish such a priority system?    Thanks for any advice

Comment: I'd like to know this too. I'm curious as to how xfinity seems to give themselves first priority to be chosen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a complete connection to the xfinity wireless network (including password). Then reconnect to your desired wireless network. Then go to the network icon in the top panel and select `Edit Connections...`. Select the xfinity wireless profile and click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button. In the `General` tab, uncheck the `Automatically connect to this network when it is available`. Then click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button. Done.

[image]

Comment: Um, I don't mind connecting automatically to xfinity when it's the only available one.  The issue is that somehow a weak xfinity connection gets chosen over a strong home LAN one.  It doesn't seem that this answer really fixes that, just prevents xfinity from ever being chosen automatically.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes... but in the **home** environment, xfinity (and its specific password) and your home network will be the only wireless choices. If you travel elsewhere, and there's (only) a xfinity network, you'll be required to give a new password, and it will create a "xfinity 2" wireless profile. So it all works as the OP and yourself requested.

Comment: Agree it's a working solution.  I've just always been curious about how xfinity manages to force itself to the top of the list.  It must be spoofing the signal strength or something.

Comment: It's especially puzzling since xfinity's signal is usually weaker than the best signal wherever I'm located